# Best way to convert a defaultdict(list) dictionary with list of dictionaries to a csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

My default dict has an **address key**  and has a list of dictionaries that match that key. I'd like to export this defaultdict to a csv file.

See below:

```
Right now my structure looks like this defaultdict(list)
#As you can see 1 key with multiple matching dictionaries. 
#And im just copying 1 address but I have ~10 w/ varying matches

defaultdic1 = 

defaultdict(list,
            {'Address_1': [{'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_1',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc'},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_2',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc'},
              {'Name': 'name',
               'Address_match': 'address_match_3',
               'ID': 'id',
               'Type': 'abc'}]})
```

I tried doing this:

```
json_data = json.dumps(data_json, indent=2)

jsondf = pd.read_json(json_data, typ = 'series')

and my result was this:

Address 1       [{'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_1' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'} {'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_2' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'}, {'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_3' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'}]
```

**Result/output:**

Id like to export this to an excel file

**Update** I tried this. The first row is printing the key but  2nd row is still in a {}, it would be great to get them out of the brackets and shifted into columns. Any tips there?

```
    for k, v in defaultdict.items():
        f.writerow([k])
        for values in v:
            f.writerow([values])

results in CSV are:

Address 1

{'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_1' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'}
{'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_1' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'}
{'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_2' 'ID' : 'id', 'Type':'abc'}
```

I'd like my results to be:

```
Address 1                Name, Address_match1, ID, Type
                         Name, Address_match2, ID, Type
                         Name, Address_match3, ID, Type

Address 2                Name1, Address_match1, ID, Type
                         Name1, Address_match1, ID, Type

Address 3                Name1, Address_match1, ID, Type
                         Name1, Address_match1, ID, Type
```

Comment: Your first code snippet isn't runnable...

Comment: I'm sorry, but what is your question?

Comment: I'm not trying to be rude, but you really need to specify your input *precisely* and your desired output *precisely*

Comment: fixed it up. I didnt want to put real info so I just threw together a defaultdic. 1 with 1 value and another with 2 values. In my real data these are all combined together. Id like to figure out how to best export this info to an excel file. Hope that clears things up. let me know if you need more info!

Comment: maybe you should use `for`-loop to work with every element on list separatelly and put every element in new row. And this doesn't need `JSON`

Comment: @furas, i didnt even think of that as an option! what would something like that look like? thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I was thinking about `for key, val in jsondefaultdic1.items(): for item in val: print(key, item)` and the same for `jsondefaultdic2`

Comment: @furas I updated my question to include my iteration. Do you know how I can remove the brackets from my  excel file results?

Comment: You can use the `csv` module's `DictWriter` to write rows directly from your dicts.

Comment: @TimRoberts another good tip, thanks. Can you help me understand how to access the inner lists of dictionaries using DictWriter?

Comment: Do you actually want those subtitle lines in there ("Address 1" etc)?  That's not really a CSV file any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up solving it!

```
names = list(dic1['Address_1'][0].keys())
f.close()
with open ("file.csv", "w", newline="") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    keys = names
    writer.writerow(["Address"] +(keys))
    for k, vl in defaultdict.items():
        for v in vl:
            writer.writerow([k] + [v[key] for key in keys])
f.close()
```

Comment: Just as a comment for the future, make sure when you ask a question that your sample data really does reflect your sample data.

Comment: @TimRoberts Will do! Your names variable got me moving, couldn't of done it without your help. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Your input data and output data do not match, so it's awfully difficult to tell how to transform things, but here is something that takes your defaultdict and converts it to a CSV file:

```
import csv

dic1 = {'Address_2': 
    [
        {'Address 1': 
            [
                {'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_1', 'ID':'id', 'Type':'abc'}
            ]
        },
        {'Address 2': 
            [
                {'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_2', 'ID':'id', 'Type':'abc'}
            ]
        }, 
        {'Address 3': 
            [
                {'Name':'name', 'Address_match':'address_match_3', 'ID':'id', 'Type':'abc'}
            ]
        }
    ]
}

names = list(dic1['Address_2'][0]['Address 1'][0].keys())

myfile = csv.DictWriter( open('xxx.csv','w'), fieldnames = names  )
for row in dic1['Address_2']:
    myfile.writerow({'Name':list(row.keys())[0]})
    myfile.writerow(list(row.values())[0][0])
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this post, I really appreciate it.  I adjusted my input and output so they should be matching. I also realized that I dont have a dictionary format like you posted for dict1, instead I have a dictionary with a list of dictionaries inside. Please see my changes.

Comment: That's what I have in my code: a dictionary with a list of dictionaries.

Comment: Yes true. I'm new to defaultdics(lists) .  This worked for me - > names = list(Address2'][0].keys()) , but names = list(dic1['Address_2'][0]['Address 1'][0].keys()) gave me an error saying 'str' object has no attribute 'keys'. I think its because I've got 1 key w/ an address. and then inside of that key I don't have another key.

Comment: Well, there is some confusion, because what you currently show in your "see below" is not a dict at all.  It is a list of dictionaries.  You don't have the "Address_2" at the root at all.

Comment: yeah I put in the comments (#) above that its just 1 address but I have ~10.  Anyways thanks fore your help I was able to solve it! Really appreciate it.  I actually didnt use DictWriter I did it using writer.